# To prove the $(\Bbb R , +)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb C , +)$ without using metric space?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Firstly, I want to show $(\Bbb R , +)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ (under component wise addition).

In this I used the mapping 
$\phi_1$ :  $\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$

Where,  $\phi_1(a,b) = 2^a3^b$

And then , show $\Bbb R^2$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb C , +)$.

In this I used the mapping

$\phi_2$ : $\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb C$

Where,   $\phi_2(a,b) = a+ib$

And then, use the transitive property of isomorphic groups to show 
$(\Bbb R , +)$  is isomorphic to  $(\Bbb C , +)$

Now ,my doubts are that, whether the mappings i used are correct or not.
Does this mappings makes the two groups isomorphic?

Please,  correct me wherever I am wrong?

Edit:
I see that $\phi_1$ is not bijective.
So , their is no way to prove ,$\phi_1$ :  $\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$   is an isomorphism by just defining a mapping or without using the concept of metric space!

Comment: $\phi_1$ is not even a morphism, it's not injective and it's not surjective : very far from an isomorphism

Comment: @Max Thanks for your help. So can you define a  mapping for this if possible & what about $\phi_2$ ?

Comment: $\phi_2$ is alright (if you're not sure, you should prove it !). However, defining $\phi_1$ is going to be complicated : we can prove that it exists but it's hard (or impossible) to actually make it explicit. The proof I know requires the axiom of choice, whereas the result does not hold without assuming any form of it, so there will be some “non-explicit part“

Comment: Your map $\phi_1$ is an injective map $\Bbb N^2\to\Bbb N,$ but isn't even surjective there. It is still injective (but not surjective) if you extend to $\Bbb Z^2\to\Bbb Q,$ or $\Bbb Q^2\to\Bbb R.$ Unfortunately, you lose injectivity when you extend it to $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R.$

Comment: I see that , most of answers to this question requires metric space.

Comment: @Arthur And also i am not familiar with metric space,  as i am just a begginer. So, their is no method of proving this isomorphism in $\phi_1$ by just simply defining a function. 

Comment: @CameronBuie yeah i noticed it as the above person said.

Comment: I do not know any answer to this that uses metric space.  I do know one using vector space.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for your help, but unfortunately the question has been closed , so i can't get any more opinions 

Comment: Did you mean "vector space" rather than "metric space"? Otherwise your question is *not* a duplicate and should be reopened.

Comment: @user1729 sorry but i don't know either of them. What i want ,is just to define a bijective mapping from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$

Comment: I think metric spaces are totally irrelevant here, you can as well ask about a proof which uses, say, the probability theory.